# Unable to generate cucumber reports in jenkins. net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: None report file was added

Tags: jenkins, report, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using jenkins to run jobs that uses maven with cucumber . my jobs are running succesfully. I have also managed the plugin Cucumber report in jenkins. But when i view the report i am getting the message as shown in below picture.

I have tried to install various plugins like Jenkins plugin, standalone but with no joy. These are shown as options in the bottom right of the report.

Any clue is helpful. I have tried to check this error in stackover flow also. I didnt get any clue

[image]

I could see the reports file in xml which is created by surefire plugin. Any way i can achive reporting part in my project

[image]

Comment: Are you able to generate the report when you run Maven from your dev env?

Comment: I have only test environment. we are using a web application for a purpose and i automated a repeated process. i am not dev or testing a process. i have automated a process and need reports on automation success and failures.

Comment: My question is rather, are you able to reproduce the behaviour outside of your CI system? Can you trouble shoot and get it to work somewhere else?

Comment: Now i got your point. I didnt try in Dev environment. But now i am fine with the resolution i made in jenkins configuration. By setting the json path for report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get reports in jenkins now.

Previously Jenkins is unable to find the json file in my project.

I have set the path of json file as target and i could able to see the reports.

Comment: As far as i remember i have set in jenkins, global parameters. So my Automation tests have one json file, just copied the path of the Json and pasted in jenkins - Global configuration

Answer (score 3):

This might help for those who are looking for answer.

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features= "C:\\Users\\dd pc\\workspace\\PracticeCucumber\\src\\main\\java\\com\\qa\\feature\\Test.feature",
        glue= {"com\\qa\\stepDefinition"},
        format= {"pretty","html:test-output_1",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json"},
        plugin = ("json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json"),
        monochrome= true,
        dryRun= false

        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve by providing **/*.json
under Post-build Actions/Cucumber Report/JSON Report Location/ File Include Pattern = **/*.json

Answer (score 0):

First of all in runner file we need to provide following plugin as follows: plugin= {"json:target/cucumber.json" }

Now in Jenkins job, in "post build" section during configuration, add cucumber reports, click on advanced option and provide 'target' text in "JSON Reports Path" text field. Save the job, it will run and will work fine.

Note: target text is the name of folder which we have provided in runner file for generating reports in Json, also cucumber report plugin works on json so need to generate report in json.

Answer (score 0):

I my case the problem was in two jobs over the same test repository (one for Chrome one for Firefox), where one deletes report files after the job while second job was already running and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

In TestRunner file you need to provide following plugin in `@CucumberOptions`:

```
plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/CucumberTestReport.json",
                    "html:target/CucumberTestReport.html"},
```

Html report generate for individual report after tests run, and json report to generate details reports in Jenkins.

Now in Jenkins job, while configuration select `cucumber reports` in post build section, click on advanced option and provide 'FULL ABSOLUTE PATH OF YOUR JSON FILE' in "JSON Reports Path" text field. Save the job, it will absolutely work fine.

To know more : https://plugins.jenkins.io/cucumber-reports/