# Cucumber Report error in Jenkins - "net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: No report file was added"

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, report, jenkins-plugins, maven-surefire-plugin

While using Jenkins to run a job (that uses maven with cucumber), the job is running successfully. 
However, when I view the cucumber report, I am getting the message as shown in below picture.

```
net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: No report file was added!
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:55)
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:90)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.generateReport(CucumberReportPublisher.java:300)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.perform(CucumberReportPublisher.java:229)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
```

I referred to [this similar issue link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585983/unable-to-generate-cucumber-reports-in-jenkins-net-masterthought-cucumber-valid), but I am not able to understand the solution and the steps taken.

1. Where in my project (in Eclipse) can I see this json file generated?
2. How can I copy the path of this json file and set it in Jenkins as  Global parameter?

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

If there is any other feasible solution to this issue, please share.

Comment: Plz share your Report Config. This seems to be a missing json file case when adding as list.  this is how it should be-                                                               File reportOutputDirectory = new File("target/yourPath");
List<String> jsonFiles = new ArrayList<>();
jsonFiles.add("target/cucumber-report.json");  -->give any path of ur choice                                                                
                   Or refer below link for more detailes on configuration, hope this helps. https://github.com/jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin/wiki/Detailed-Configuration

Answer (score 0):

@Kirti Gupta,

I encountered a similar issue and could resolve it after downgrading the version of maven-cucumber-reporting to 3.15.0.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Finally solved the issue.
For me the issue was I had added the cucumber DSL code and the mvn test code to build the tests in different instances of 'selenium' agent in Jenkins file. So the files were not copied from workspace.

After moving the cucumber code to build stage (test build and cucumber report in same stage), it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: No JSON report file was found! indicates that the Cucumber Report Jenkins plugin is unable to find any JSON report files to generate the report. This can happen if the JSON files are not generated, or if they are not in the expected location.

To fix this error, you will need to make sure that the JSON report files are generated by your Cucumber tests. If you are using the cucumber-JVM library, you can use the JSON: reporter to generate JSON report files. For example

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json"}
)
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

This will generate a JSON report file at target/cucumber.json that can be used by the Cucumber Report Jenkins plugin.

You will also need to make sure that the JSON report files are located in the expected location. The Cucumber Report Jenkins plugin looks for JSON report files in the target directory by default. If you are generating the JSON report files in a different location, you will need to specify that location in the plugin configuration.

To do this, go to the Jenkins configuration page and navigate to the Cucumber Report plugin configuration. In the "JSON reports path" field, enter the path to the directory where the JSON report files are located. For example, if the JSON report files are located in the output directory, you would enter output in the "JSON reports path" field. Save your changes and run the build again to generate the Cucumber report. This should fix the No JSON report file found! error.

Answer (score 0):

In TestRunner file you need to provide following plugin in @CucumberOptions:

plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/CucumberTestReport.json", "html:target/CucumberTestReport.html"},

Html report generate for individual report after tests run, and json report to generate details reports in Jenkins.

Now in Jenkins job, while configuration select "cucumber reports" in post build section, click on advanced option and provide 'FULL ABSOLUTE PATH OF YOUR JSON FILE' in "JSON Reports Path" text field. Save the job, it will absolutely work fine.

To know more : https://plugins.jenkins.io/cucumber-reports/