# Jenkins unable to compile all JSON reports for specific builds (net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: Passed files have no features!)?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, cucumber

Specific Jenkins builds are not compiling Json reports and seem to be throwing an exception:

```
net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: Passed files have no features!
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:78)
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:88)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.generateReport(CucumberReportPublisher.java:419)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.perform(CucumberReportPublisher.java:336)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1074)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1840)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

For example:

Build: #9, #10, #12- json reports compiled okay.

Build: #11, #13 - failed to compile the json reports.

Jenkins Version:2.195
Cucumber Reports Version: 4.10.0

Comment: set the path of json file as target Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585983/unable-to-generate-cucumber-reports-in-jenkins-net-masterthought-cucumber-valid

Comment: @Shubham Jain I have already set the path as instructed but still face the same issue